# Adding plugin to hundred wordpress websites

Tags: php, wordpress, automation

We have 100 websites all have wordpress installed on them . I need to keep GUI and admin interface for all the same . I know I can use MU / MultiSite but I evaluated that option and I dont want to go that route . Is there any other way to add a plugin to all websites automatically ? Writing some script that can do it ?

Comment: Adding the plugin is as simple as copying it to the plugins directory. Activating it is a different story though, although I suspect that could be scripted with some careful work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Infinitewp](http://infinitewp.com/) to manage multiple wordpress sites.